# Как создать обычную строку из строки в формате html на Objective-c

Tags: html, c++, objective-c, парсер, corefoundation

Есть строка формата, например как эта (взятая отсюда -> [Objective C HTML escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)):

```
 string str = "&lt;span&gt;Foo&lt;/span&gt;";
```

Вопрос в том: как превратить её в строку вида:

```
<span>Foo</span>
```

**С ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ CORE FOUNDATION ИЛИ С/С++???**

Можно так же предлагать реализации на С/С++, но что-то готовое, а то не охота составлять словарь из всех возможных символов и использовать их для поиска вхождения в строку.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вот, например, решение с [кастомной категорией](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2843443/276994). Чем оно не подходит? Всё равно в общем итоге всё сводится к большой таблице.

Comment: @VladD, потому что это НЕ Core Foundation.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы была _одна функция_, которую вы вызываете, и она делает всё как надо? Судя по разнообразию ответов по вашей ссылке, такой простой функции нет. А в решении вроде бы core foundation + пара циклов, не более.

Comment: @ VladD, насколько я понимаю, если бы это был Core Foundation Framework, то вместо NSString было бы CFString. И код на гитхабе выглядит как код на чистом Objective с Cocoa. Может, я, конечно, чего-то не замечаю, ткните носом пожалуйста)

Comment: А, понял, сорри. Недооценил глубину различий между CF и остальным.

Answer (score 1):

Нашла решение вот здесь: [C++ Replacing HTML Character Entities [RESOLVED]](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?448809-C-Replacing-HTML-Character-Entities&p=1698121#post1698121).
Правда, не совсем поняла, зачем он ставит пробелы после '&' перед '#'. Убрала пробелы и у меня заработало. Привожу код, который работает у меня:

```
string htmlEntitiesDecode (string str) {

    string subs[] = {
        "&#34;", "&quot;",
        "&#39;", "&apos;",
        "&#38;", "&amp;",
        "&#60;", "&lt;",
        "&#62;", "&gt;",
        "&34;", "&39;",
        "&38;", "&60;",
        "&62;"
    };

    string reps[] = {
        "\"", "\"",
        "'", "'",
        "&", "&",
        "<", "<",
        ">", ">",
        "\"", "'",
        "&", "<",
        ">"
    };

    size_t found;
    for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        do {
            found = str.find(subs[j]);
            if (found != string::npos)
                str.replace (found,subs[j].length(),reps[j]);
        } while (found != string::npos);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Однако, это ведь далеко не все символы html-кодировки. Видимо, придётся их все перечислять. Может кто-то посоветует более красивое решение?

**P.S.:** привожу ресурс со списком символов html-кодировки:
[List of XML and HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references),
однако тут неполный список и нет кодов для html5. А вот тут есть всё:
[HTML5 символы и коды](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).